# Stop going to error function with button click / page change during Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jquery mobile, cordova/phonegap.
I have a jquery ajax call in the page load which brings some data from server. A error function is attached with it because of the 'timeout' & 'page not found' or 'server is down' situations. Function shows some alert like "something went wrong". Good so far.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/blabla.php',  //load data 
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: data,
        async: true,
        timeout: 40000,
        success: loading_complete_list,
        error: errorfunc
    });
```

Now suppose user clicked in a page. Suddenly thought "Oh! no! what have I done.. Let's press the back button" Problem starts. Error function is invoked as ajax call is not completed. Then the alert messages are shown. But I don't want that. I want the user to go wherever s/he wants to go, whenever s/he wants to go.

I want to know if it's possible to go to a different page without completing the ajax call. I can't make the error function blank as 'timeout','server down' situations need some message to be shown. I tried

```
async: false,
```

But that actually waits for the ajax call to over then execute the button press action. And the back button uses simple

```
document.location="index.html;" //This style can't be changed
```

So how can I stop error function to invoke while going to another page and invoke otherwise. What I'm missing? Can you think of any idea to detect the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess no more solution ideas..... I solved it for now using error function parameters.

using this:

```
function errorfunc(jqXHR, exception) {

     console.log(jqXHR.status);
     console.log(exception);
     ............................

}
```

By checking this results I'm giving custom messages and ignoring which I don't want to caught.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your button click function, you should add something like

```
request.abort();
```

Where request is a handler to the ajax request

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/blabla.php',  //load data 
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: data,
        async: true,
        timeout: 40000,
        success: loading_complete_list,
        error: errorfunc
    });
```

Just keep the handler somewhere (for god sake, not in global scope) to be able to access it from your button onClick function

This should abort the request and not call the error handler.

Comment: Though I've already solved it using error function parameters `errorfunc(jqXHR, exception)` but your solution looks more robust. Thanks I'll try it.
One question: Why not in global scope? Actually I can't see any other way rather declaring in the global scope.

Comment: Well, i really don't like declaring variables in global scope. It's not a trash.
What you can do is a class holding your data and function related to the page, then using this->... to access thoses data. This class would be global, but only this class, not 999 attributes.  And it's true for every language i know. Polluting global scope is not a good idea.

Comment: `request.abort();` this one still calling the errorfunc

Comment: Well, i saw somewhere it's just aborting the request, making the client stop listening on the response. So, theorically it should have prevent error callback from being called. My bad, that was wrong.